# Push notification when app is in the background on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I've been trying to get push notifications to work on Android TV using FCM. I was able to get the notification when the app is in foreground, but since there is a notification tray in Android TV, I'm not able to show notifications when the app is in the background. What approach should I use here to get the notification when the app is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The notification arrives when the app is on the background of the payload is correct according to the guidelines.

What to do with it once or arrives is up to you.

What I did is to create a toast with a custom view and show it, so the notification is displayed but the current activity on foreground does not get disrupted.

As you said, there's no notification tray on Android TV, so you have to come up with your own solution.

Comment: When my TV app is in background 'data' in payload is not receiving in onMessageReceived. I want to show a custom toast when FCM arrived when app is in bg. Please suggest how you did this?

Comment: It depends on how you send the payload. There is one configuration that relies on the system and one that always invokes your method. You might be using the one that relies on the OS when the app is not on foreground.
For more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive